# iOS use different Mail Client from own app? (Citrix)

Tags: ios, swift, email, citrix

I would like to use an different Mail client to send E-Mails from an iOS App. Its a Business Software, so the secure mail client from citrix would be installed anyways.

I know that i am able to use an URL scheme to open a different app - but i my case i need to add an specific attachment to the mail.

**Is it possible to add secure mail client to all QLPreviewControllers (where i am able to send the displayed file to an user?)**

Or can i just simple make an custom button to open the secure mail client with an url scheme?

So in that case:

```
if let
    urlString = "mailto:=ctxmail:\(toEmail)?subject=\(subject)&body=\(body)",
    url = URL(string:urlString) {
    UIApplication.shared().openURL(url)
}
```

As seen here:

https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/mdx-toolkit/10/xmob-mobile-app-policy-defaults/xmob-mdx-policies-ios.html

Comment: For what it's worth, your question seems pretty valid to me ;-) Upvoted!

Comment: Thanks :) ive searched the web for about 1 hour - and no solution how i am able to implement it to all QLPreviewControllers (for example just change the default mail client)

Comment: Have you found any solution for attachments?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the custom URL scheme you mentioned, assuming we can work around that attachment requirement. It might be a better future-proof solution since you won't be depending on a specific API behavior.

Since iOS 10 the system provides a built-in *back button* between apps, so your UX shouldn't be affected too much by this design decision (i.e., with a *single tap* the user can go back to your app).

Comment: But i am not finding any information if its possible to add the secure mail client (or any other third party mail client) to the QLPreviewController (which automatically opens the default Mail App from Apple)

Comment: And my second problem: It seems that mailto: do not support adding attachments

Comment: Maybe you can use [deep linking](https://www.programmableweb.com/news/how-to-implement-deep-linking-ios/how-to/2015/07/14) here? Of course, assuming Citrix mail app supports such feature...

Comment: Thanks for your answer - but it seems citrix does not support deep linking.

Comment: BTW, any chance you could upload that attachment and then add a link to it in the email body?

Comment: If i am unable to find any other solution - yes ;)